# Included Recipient List and Total Recipient count is not identical in EXM 3.3

Tags: exm

We are using Sitecore 8.1 (rev. 160519) and Email Experience Manager 3.3.0 rev. 16052. EXM is up and running.

I have segmented list with some custom rules.
When I create a EXM new campaign and add a segmented list the count showing in included recipient list and Total recipient list of Email campaign info is not identical.

Could you please assist what I can do to make it identical? Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you check Excluded recipient list? seems like out of 157 total contacts, 35 are included in the global opt-out list.

Comment: @RamanGupta Excluded list count is zero. Is it something excluded recipient out out logic is not working? or can it be indexing issue?